# MySQL User Permission Error on Specific Select Query

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

When running a csv export query in MySQL I am getting an access denied error.

The query in question is:

```
SELECT id_no, name, address
FROM master
INTO OUTFILE '/Users/home/go_results.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

This results in:

```
Access denied for user 'user'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

The same user can run a range of other select, create and so on queries.

I am using AWS RDS so I do not have root access or I would run from there.

Comment: That out file goes to the server's local file system, not the client's. You can't access it since it is on RDS.

Answer (score 1):

`user` does not have the required privilege.

From MySQL [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html)

> The file is created on the server host, so you must have the FILE
>   privilege

Execute the following statement:

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'user'@'%'
```

Also note that as @Anthony Neace pointed out in his comment and as is stated in the documentation, the `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` syntax will create a file on the server. Although your question wasn't related to that so the answer stands.

Comment: It is precisely related to OP's question because they specified they are in the Amazon RDS environment. It is in-fact the entire reason why this answer won't work for them.  `SELECT... INTO OUTFILE` is not supported on Amazon RDS.  More details: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=162499#162499

Comment: Thanks, Anthony! While it won't work on RDS, in this answer there is a resolution to that particular problem the OP specified (Why is there a MySQL permission error for that statement). It is a good practice to let the OP know that he really wanted ask something else, but not to down-vote an answered to what really was asked.

Comment: No, I disagree; OP included that detail from their initial posting and it is an important part of the question since it invalidates your answer. It is doing a disservice to the OP to suggest that they asked the wrong question because you answered the wrong question.  I would _strongly_ agree with you if they edited that detail in after the fact because it is unfair to the answerer to change the nature of the question, but that is not what happened here.

Comment: I generally agree with you. While the last line of the question invalidates the question itself from the OP's perspective apart from that last line the information provided may be useful in other cases so I'm not removing my answer.

Comment: Thanks guys! My issue is now solved ;) As you say Marekful, the last line changes things. I appreciate your answer but it was Anthony that truly cut to the chase ;)